# Fira to Santorini Airport transportation early in the morning

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, greece

Due to COVID-19 our leaving flight from Santorini, Greece to Athens (middle of September) got moved early in the morning. We are scheduled to leave from Santorini Airport at 06:20 (in the morning).
Therefore we have to be at the airport at 05:00 in the morning.
What (safe) means of transportation are there in order to get from Fira to the airport in time? We're thinking of leaving our accommodation at around 04:00.
What options do we have? Taxi, bus? Any shuttle service?

Answer (score 2):

Take a taxi.  There are plenty of taxis on Santorini.  Just make sure you arrange the trip ahead of time, given the early hour.  I would expect that your accommodation can help you order a taxi for the right time.

Answer (score 2):

Similar case here some years ago. We arranged a Taxi with the hotel the day before (around 20€ from Imerovigli)